# Email sending from Gmail API are going to SPAM

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap, gmail-addons, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I have a setup going on from long time. But from recently any emails I send through Gmail API are directly going to spam folder.

I have taken care of all email sending measures like SPF, DKIM, DMARC, Reputation etc. But I don't know where the error is occurring. Any new updates are there in Gmail API. If so please let me know.

Can anyone please help me regarding this. It will be a big helpful.

Awaiting for the response.

Thanks,
Reshu.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I met the same problem. Would you mind to share the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/cnXXfCZ0YjA), this might mean that the messages contain some sort of similarity with other messages flagged as spam. It is recommended to either change the format of the messages or modifying its content partially until achieving the expected results.

> For example, I'd remove signatures, links or any other type of redirection or repetitive item. I'd also recommend making sure that you comply with our [bulk senders guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en) described in the attached Help Center reference.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem before and it turned out to be the IP address and the domain name not registered to the same owner.
some companies check these info and block all emails or forward it to the spam folders.

Comment: I think you're right. Any ideas as to how to get around this?